# Lead someone to make a statement

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Is the verb "lead" used in the sense of "getting someone to do something by a cunning" Does the phrase "lead someone to say something" make sense? Also, would it make sense if I turned it around e.g. "Don't let be led into saying that!". 
Would the preposition "on" change anything: "Don't let be led on into saying that!".

Comment: One of the basic rules of this site is that you must do your own research before posting here, and you must include the results of your research in your post. Please edit your post and add the results of your research.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one of the meanings of ***[to lead](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lead)*** 
is:

> to cause someone to do something, especially something bad:
>
> [ + *to infinitive ] The brochure led me to believe that the price included home delivery.*

also in the passive form:

> *It's worrying that such a prominent politician is so easily led.*

I think you can use the verb in your sentence.

​***to lead somebody on:*** means:

> to persuade someone to believe something that is untrue:
>   *All that time she'd been leading him on (= pretending she liked him), but she was only interested in his money.*